# How is parameter passing in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, parameter-passing

I am new to objective-C, and I am familiar with C++.
I want to know how is parameter passing in objective C.
In C++, I have a function

```
void func(int a);
```

then if I call this function by

```
func(someVariable);
```

It indeed execute:

```
int a = someVariable;
```

and func processes a.
If above code makes sense, then the parameter passing is valid, otherwise not.

But in objective-C, it seems not:

I have a NSMutableString *string. Then I use the sentence

```
[string deleteCharactersInRange: {2,3}];
```

and it compiles failed.

As deleteCharactersInrange: is defined:

```
- (void) deleteCharacterInRange: (NSRange) aRange;
```

So I think it can execute

```
NSRange aRange = {2,3};
```

which is valid.

Comment: It should be `NSMakeRange(2, 3)` instead of `{2, 3}`

Comment: `NSMakeRange()` usually for the creation of range. Also, compilation fails? What's the error thrown by XCode? Or sometimes `NSRangeFromString(@"{2,3}"}`

Comment: @trungduc I know NSMakeRange(2, 3) can do, but I wonder why {2, 3} can't

Comment: @Evian For example, you can write `CGSize size = {2, 3}`. So if you only write `{2, 3}`, do you know what kind of class or struct for `{2, 3}`? `CGSize` or `NSRange`?

Comment: @trungduc So how does the parameter passing in objective-C work? As I state above, I think the validation of initializing sentence determines the success of parameter passing, but if so, NSRange aRange = {2, 3} is also valid, but the parameter passing is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter passing in Objective-C is just the same as parameter passing in C. Parameter passing in Objective-C++ is just the same as in C++.

You are reasoning from your belief that parameter passing is the same as initialization. That belief is incorrect.

Note that:

```
void foo(NSRange r);

...

foo({2,3});
```

is not legal C, C++, Objective-C, or Objective-C++. That's exactly the same situation as `[string deleteCharactersInRange: {2,3}]`, which is why the compiler complains about that, too.

Note that, while `NSMakeRange()` is certainly appropriate, you can also use `(NSRange){2, 3}`.

Comment: Thanks! So is the whole process of parameter passing: 1. determine whether the type of the parameter being passed matches the argument of function 2. Doing the initialization ?

Comment: I believe it's the same semantics as assignment (which is not the same as initialization).